# Getting the same response different URL

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, url, request

I'm getting the same response from these 2 URLs:

- [First URL](https://www.amazon.it/blackfriday?ref_=nav_cs_gb_td_bf_dt_cr&deals-widget=%257B%2522version%2522%253A1%252C%2522viewIndex%2522%253A0%252C%2522presetId%2522%253A%2522deals-collection-all-deals%2522%252C%2522sorting%2522%253A%2522BY_SCORE%2522%257D)
- [Second URL](https://www.amazon.it/blackfriday?ref_=nav_cs_gb_td_bf_dt_cr&deals-widget=%257B%2522version%2522%253A1%252C%2522viewIndex%2522%253A60%252C%2522presetId%2522%253A%2522deals-collection-all-deals%2522%252C%2522sorting%2522%253A%2522BY_SCORE%2522%257D)

This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.amazon.it/blackfriday"

querystring = {"ref_":"nav_cs_gb_td_bf_dt_cr","deals-widget":"{\"version\":1,\"viewIndex\":60,\"presetId\":\"deals-collection-all-deals\",\"sorting\":\"BY_SCORE\"}"}

payload = ""
headers = {"cookie": "session-id=260-4643637-2647537; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=EUR; ubid-acbit=258-7747562-7485655; session-token=%22aZB70z2dnXHbhJ9e02ESp7q6xO23IGnDFT2iBCiPXZFoBTTEguAJ%2FBSnV7ud6bjAca64nh3bMF1bwDykOBf9BV%2BVjbx4tUQCyBkrg8tyR8PLZ8cjzpCz%2FzQSAmjiL6mSBcspkF8xuV0bxqLeRX7JQCMrHVBFf%2BsUhxV%2FMBLCH8UPk2o5aNL7OyAFCODBdRqm72RK5DAoKeMUymlVEOtqzvZSJbP%2Fut0gobiXJblRM2c%3D%22"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

I would like to get the same response that i get on the browser
How can i do it? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to trick the server into thinking you are a browser. You can accomplish this by setting the user agent header.

```
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36',"cookie": "session-id=260-4643637-2647537; session-id-time=2082787201l; i18n-prefs=EUR; ubid-acbit=258-7747562-7485655; session-token=%22aZB70z2dnXHbhJ9e02ESp7q6xO23IGnDFT2iBCiPXZFoBTTEguAJ%2FBSnV7ud6bjAca64nh3bMF1bwDykOBf9BV%2BVjbx4tUQCyBkrg8tyR8PLZ8cjzpCz%2FzQSAmjiL6mSBcspkF8xuV0bxqLeRX7JQCMrHVBFf%2BsUhxV%2FMBLCH8UPk2o5aNL7OyAFCODBdRqm72RK5DAoKeMUymlVEOtqzvZSJbP%2Fut0gobiXJblRM2c%3D%22"}
```